# orphans are not getting deleted once changing the parent set JPA 2 + Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am probably doing something wrong, but i can not figure out what.
i have 2 tables with 2 entities with the following mapping

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Getter
    private List<ChildBase> childs;

    public Parent(){

      this.childs = new ArrayList ();

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class ChildBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    protected Parent parent;

    public ChildBase(Parent parent){
      this.parent = parent;
      }

}


@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyChild extends ChildBase {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public MyChild(String name, Parent parent) {
        super(parent);
        this.name = name;
    }
```

the problem appears once i try to disconnect a parent from a child with the following test:

```
@Test
public void test(){

Parent parent = new Parent();
MyChild child1 = new MyChild("a", parent);
MyChild child2 = new MyChild("a", parent);
parent.getChilds.add(child1);
parentRepository.save(parent);

parent.getChilds.remove(child1);
parent.getChilds.add(child2);
parentRepository.save(parent);
}
```

i am expecting to see only the second child row in "childs" table, but i see them both.

Edit:

i have tried as well to reference null from child before second save like this: child1.setParent(null).
it does not help either

Comment: before the parent is saved again have you checked, the child list has only child2 object.

Comment: of course i have checked it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bidirectional relation and `MyChild` respectively `ChildBase` is your owning side of the relation.

To trigger the orphan-removal you have to `child1.setParent(null)`, too.

UPDATE: did a setup provided from chat. here are the classes and it is working totally fine.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Getter
    private List<ChildBase> childs;

    public Parent(){

      this.childs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class ChildBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    protected long id;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    protected Parent parent;

    public ChildBase(Parent parent){
      this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyChild extends ChildBase {
  
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public MyChild(String name, Parent parent) {
        super(parent);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And here is the test. After executing there is only `childB` in the database.

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        MyChild child1 = new MyChild("childA", parent);
        MyChild child2 = new MyChild("childB", parent);
        parent.getChilds().add(child1);
        parentRepository.save(parent);

        parent.getChilds().remove(child1); // first remove
        child1.setParent(null);            // set parent null

        parent.getChilds().add(child2);
        parentRepository.save(parent);
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Change ChildBase annotation from `@Entity` to `@MappedSuperclass` and add `@EqualsAndHashcode` but exclude the `parent` field.

Comment: add the `@EqualsAndHashcode ` in the `ChildBase`?

Comment: correct. of you omit it, the java-default euquals is used. but in this case you should to equality check only on the id. additionally remove `@EqualsAndHashcode` from MyChild

Comment: Ah! And I don't know what case you are testing, but usually the parent is saved with the child in a first action (e.g. web-request) and in a second action you delete the first child and the second gets added. so between those actions the parent gets loaded from database. you should add a `parent = parentRepository.findById(parent.getId())` and then remove and add the childs.

Comment: 2 things. first i can not use the `MappedSuperclass` annotation because the parent mapping `OneToMany` keeps a collection of the base class, it just fails on entityManagerFactory bean creation. second, i have tried to use the `parentRepository.findById(parent.getId())` just after the first save and assigned the result to the father as you suggested, but something weird happens.. instead of deleting the first child in the end of the test i see only **the first** child in the DB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237128/discussion-between-lazyprophet-and-dev93).